# Bean Validation XML entire bean

Tags: java, xml, validation, bean-validation

I am **required** to use bean validation using XML.

We can validate the whole class by putting annotations just before the class declaration.

```
@AtLeastOneNotNull
public class SampleBean {
    // ...
}
```

And then use reflection to loop over the fields.

---

How can I achieve the same thing using XML bean validation?

```
<constraint-mappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping">

    <default-package>my.package</default-package>
    <bean class="SampleBean">
        <!-- ? -->
    </bean>
</constraint-mappings>
```

All I can declare after `<bean>` is `<field>`.

My goal is to validate multiple fields dependencies using XML bean validation.
For example :

- at least one field must be filled
- if `field1` is `null` then `field2` isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the [documentation](http://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#xml-mapping-constraintdeclarationinxml-classleveloverriding) for Bean Validation 2.0 (If you still use the older version - here's the same [link](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#d0e5769) to 1.0 version) There's Example 9.2 showing what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<constraint-mappings
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/mapping/validation-mapping-2.0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <default-package>com.acme.app.domain</default-package>
    <bean class="Customer" ignore-annotations="false">
        <class ignore-annotations="true">
            [...]
        </class>
    </bean>

</constraint-mappings>
```

So to answer your question you should be able to put:

```
<bean class="SampleBean" ignore-annotations="false">
    <class ignore-annotations="true">
        [...]
    </class>
</bean>
```

and define your constraints. Also if you are using Hibernate Validator you might want to look at ScripAssert constraint - it would allow you to write a simple script check and you wouldn't need to write your own constraint for checking if at least one filed is not null. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and for giving the documentation link. I don't know why the autocompletion using the XSD only propose `field`.